# Slick slider Изменение dots

Tags: html, jquery, css, slick.js

Нужно чтобы картинки были разными, а при разрешении меньше 768px стали точками.

И Почему-то текст с data-title не считывается

https://codepen.io/st-iv/pen/PKQWMJ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
  customPaging : function(slider, i) {
  var title = $(slider.$slides[i]).data('title');
  return '<a class="pager__item"></a>';
```

Comment: jquery data это не аттрибут data-*, используйте $(slider.$slides[i]).attr('data-title')

Answer (score 2):

1. С чего вы взяли, что текст с data-title не считывается, Вы его просто не используете, пример использования

```js
    return '<a class="pager__item">' + title +'</a>';
```

2. Чтобы были картинки разные, обычно их урл используют в data-thumb, пример:

   < div data-thumb="007MS.png">< img src="Spr_3f_007.png">< /div>
3. Чтобы при маленьких разрешениях они ставали точками, можно сделать так:

```js
    customPaging : function(slider, i) {
            var thumb = $(slider.$slides[i]).data('thumb');
            return '<a class="dot-trumb"><img src="'+thumb+'"></a>';
        },
```

```css
    @media (max-width:992px) {
    .dot-trumb img {
       display:none;
     }
    
    .dot-trumb {
      display:inline-block;
      width:15px;
      height: 15px;
      background: #333;
      border-radius: 10px;
    }

   //меняем цвет активного элемента
   .slick-active .dot-trumb { background: #777;}
    }
```

Comment: Супер! а как изменить цвет точки, если она активная?

Comment: .slick-active  .dot-trumb { background: #777;}

Comment: пытаюсь сделать но почему то dots налазят друг на друга https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZsQ9.png  хотя pager__item присваиваю margin всё равно налазят друг на друга